# Broadcast advanced indexing numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of values for example

```
x = array([[[-0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.        ,  0.78867513,  0.21132487,    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
            [ 0.        , -0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.        ,  0.78867513,    0.21132487,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
            [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.78867513, -0.21132487,    0.        ,  0.78867513,  0.21132487,  0.        ],
            [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.78867513,   -0.21132487,  0.        ,  0.78867513,  0.21132487]],
           [[-0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.        ,  0.78867513,  0.21132487,    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
            [ 0.        , -0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.        ,  0.78867513,    0.21132487,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
            [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.78867513, -0.21132487,    0.        ,  0.78867513,  0.21132487,  0.        ],
            [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.78867513,   -0.21132487,  0.        ,  0.78867513,  0.21132487]]])
```

I want in use advanced indexing to pull out the nonzero values.  I know the indices of the nonzero values so

```
idx = array([[4, 3, 1, 0],
             [5, 4, 2, 1],
             [7, 6, 4, 3],
             [8, 7, 5, 4]])
```

The desired result would be something like

```
x[idx] = array([[[-0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.78867513,  0.21132487],
                 [-0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.78867513,  0.21132487],
                 [-0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.78867513,  0.21132487],
                 [-0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.78867513,  0.21132487]],
                [[-0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.78867513,  0.21132487],
                 [-0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.78867513,  0.21132487],
                 [-0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.78867513,  0.21132487],
                 [-0.78867513, -0.21132487,  0.78867513,  0.21132487]]])
```

The actual `x` array is much larger along the first dimension, but the nonzero structure is always indicated by `idx` so I need it to broadcast along the first dimension.  Is this possible?

EDIT: To be clear `x` along the first dimension contains a nested list of `4 x 9` array.  `idx` then has the nonzero entries row-for-row.  Notice in the first row of the both `4 x 9` nested arrays in `x` that the `4 3 1 0` entries are nonzero.

Comment: It's not clear how `idx` relates to which elements are nonzero.

Comment: Added and edit to  clarify.

Comment: Does the order of the elements along the second axis of `idx` have any meaning? I would have expected the elements of your desired output to be in a different order. Also, is it guaranteed that `x` will be structured in such a way that `idx` doesn't need to be jagged?

Comment: Yes, they should be in order so there should be a change in +/- signs.  Sorry for the mistake

Comment: Also, `idx` will never be jagged, always rectangular.

Comment: Could you please change your desired output accordingly to avoid further confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
x[:,np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None],idx]
```

Using this technique every element in `np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None]` (which has shape (idx.shape[0], 1) and therefore is a column vector) will be broadcast with every row in idx. This will then be used for all entries along x's first axis.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one liner for your problem and it seems to do the job without needing `idx`. You may need to change the parameter in `.reshape()` according to the size of your problem.

```
np.array(filter(lambda x: x!=0, x.ravel())).reshape(-1, 4, 4)
```

It flattens the array, removes the zeroes and then changes it back to the required shape.

Here's another version which is probably more efficient as it does not use the `filter` function and uses *boolean indexing* for numpy arrays instead

```
y = x.ravel()
z = y[y!=0].reshape(-1, 4, 4)
```

**EDIT:**

While playing around with numpy I discovered yet another way to do it.

```
x[x!=0].reshape(-1, 4, 4)
```

And here's the performance of all three method:

- Method 1: `10000  loops, best of 3: 21.2 µs per loop`
- Method 2: `100000 loops, best of 3: 2.42 µs per loop`
- Method 3: `100000 loops, best of 3: 1.97 µs per loop`

Comment: I would be interested in seeing if casting as a boolean, with flattening and reshaping, as in my prior post, is as fast or faster than the `x!=0` approach, which involves a different type of comparison I think.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor I tried profiling your second method and it is almost the same. Here's what I got `100000 loops, best of 3: 2.35 µs per loop`

Comment: Thanks much Lakshay Gang... I was thinking that perhaps casting was better than an `x!=0` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a bit odd, but here goes...

```
idxes = np.ones((x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1), dtype=bool) * idx
print x[np.array(x, dtype=bool)].reshape(idxes.shape)
```

And of course you must remember to write `np.array` rather than `array`.

Cheers!

And you can unburden yourself from computing idx with the following:

```
y = x[np.array(x, dtype=bool)]
print y.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], y.size/x.shape[0]/x.shape[1])
```

With this or the lines above it's the casting of the floats as bools that provides a mask that eliminates the zeros.