# Theano advanced indexing for tensor, shared index

Tags: python, theano

I have a tensor `probs` with `probs.shape = (max_time, num_batches, num_labels)`.

And I have a tensor `targets` with `targets.shape = (max_seq_len, num_batches)` where the values are label indices, i.e. for the third dimension in `probs`.

Now I want to get a tensor `probs_y` with `probs.shape = (max_time, num_batches, max_seq_len)` where the third dimension is the index in `targets`. Basically

```
probs_y[:,i,:] = probs[:,i,targets[:,i]]
```

for all `0 <= i < num_batches`.

How can I achieve this?

A similar problem with solution was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31043630/133374).

The solution there, if I understand correctly, would be:

```
probs_y = probs[:,T.arange(targets.shape[1])[None,:],targets]
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I get:
`` IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices ``.

Also, isn't the creation of the temporal `T.arange` a bit costly? Esp when I try to workaround by really making it a full dense integer array. There should be a better way.

Maybe `theano.map`? But as far as I understand, that doesn't parallelize the code, so this is also not a solution.

Comment: Just realized that all I did differently from your line is that I transposed the axes both in the `T.arange` and the `targets`. This is weird. Yours should have worked, too, in that case.

Comment: OK, the way you do it also works, I updated my answer. So the problem is elsewhere. Either theano version or something not pertaining to this specific operation - although given the error message the latter seems improbable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

max_time, num_batches, num_labels = 3, 4, 6
max_seq_len = 5

probs_ = np.arange(max_time * num_batches * num_labels).reshape(
    max_time, num_batches, num_labels)

targets_ = np.arange(num_batches * max_seq_len).reshape(max_seq_len, 
    num_batches) % (num_batches - 1)  # mix stuff up

probs, targets = map(theano.shared, (probs_, targets_))

print probs_
print targets_

probs_y = probs[:, T.arange(targets.shape[1])[:, np.newaxis], targets.T]

print probs_y.eval()
```

Above used a transposed version of your indices. Your exact proposition also works

```
probs_y2 = probs[:, T.arange(targets.shape[1])[np.newaxis, :], targets]

print probs_y2.eval()
print (probs_y2.dimshuffle(0, 2, 1) - probs_y).eval()
```

So maybe your problem is somewhere else.

As for speed, I am at a loss as to what could be faster than this. `map`, which is a specialization of `scan` almost certainly is not. I do not know to what extent the `arange` is actually built rather than simply iterated over.

Comment: Thanks, my example actually also worked. In my test code, `probs` mistakenly was still a `numpy.ndarray`. :P

Comment: Aaaah OK - I must have done this before, too, because the error message seemed very familiar.